# Stress - Load testing a web application

Tags: java, tomcat, testing, servlets, stress-testing

I have a web application deployed on a tomcat server.
I upload files via a POST method and then the uploaded
files are transcoded to another type (e.g. 3gp to flv).
How can I test, how many concurrent uploads and transcodings
my web application can handle?

Any thoughts or any examples?
Don't know a thing about stress or load testing

Answer (score 4):

I've never used it, but look into [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/). It does load testing for Java.