# Load Testing Async Tasks

Tags: java, android, performance-testing

I was interested in load testing code that is executed within AsyncTasks in Android. Over 50K users will download and be the app, and each app does JSON polling via Async Tasks.  What is a good way for me to test fetch and json parsing of data under load?  Essentially I want to execute the `doInBackground` code simulating multiple concurrent users.  Perhaps the AsyncTask aspect is not so important but I do need to at least test not only the HTTP fetch but also my parsing logic.  I could perhaps move this code into an executable java block outside AsyncTask.

What load testing tool should I use for this?

Comment: Have you considered JMeter http://jmeter.apache.org ?

Comment: This question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/6015168/130224, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4350711/130224, and http://stackoverflow.com/q/3851229/130224.

Answer (score 0):

[JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) is a popular open-source load testing tool that you should consider.

Comment: Ok. How could I run a block of Java code using JMeter that has HttpClient inside and parser logic? Would it work for this?